# Having trouble inputting into tinymce via selenium

Tags: python, selenium, tinymce

In selenium i am trying to enter text into the tinymce text area, but i am having trouble selecting the text area to input the text. Is there a way to select the text area behind tinymce or anyway to select tinymce so i can enter text. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use command: runScript 
Target:  tinyMCE.get('text_area_id').setContent('Your text here')

or you can use tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('Your text here') which will select either the first or the last mceEditor, I forget..

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
tinymce.get('your_editor_id').focus();
```

In case you have one single editor on your page you may also use

```
tinymce.editors[0].focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    driver.execute_script("tinymce.get('{0}').focus()".format('id_of_textarea'))
    driver.execute_script("tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('{0}')".format('your text here'))
```

it works for me
(cant remember where i saw it thought)